# Perl script cant find Net/SSH/Perl.pm

Tags: perl, ssh

Im trying to run a perl script which involves ssh to a remote server and while executing this code, it throws an error like

```
Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in INC <@INC contains:C:/Perl/site/lib c:\perl\lib  at line5.
```

I open ppm graphical UI and installed NET-SSH, area= site 
but still not able to execute this script
Here is the script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $ip=12.14.142.22;
my $user = "qwerty";
my $pass = "termide";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($ip, use_pty => 1);

$ssh->login($user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Foo::Bar often includes a Foo::Bar::Baz module, that isn't the case here.

[Net::SSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH) and  [Net::SSH::Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aPerl) are different distributions. You need to install Net::SSH::Perl.

Comment: Any idea how to install that in a windows machine?

Comment: Not for ActiveState Perl. I use Strawberry Perl when I need to use Windows, and that is just a case of `cpan Net::SSH::Perl`

Answer (score 3):

You should install `Net::SSH::Perl`, not `Net::SSH`. The error message is clean about that :)

Comment: Any idea how to install that in a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

[Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2) is another SSH client that works on Windows and far easier to install. A PPM is available from [here](http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/Net-SSH2.ppd).